# Long paths bug in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, xmldocument

I have the following file:

```
C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AzureTests\Build\82df3c44-0482-47a7-a5d8-9b39a79cf359.cskpg\WebRole1_778722b2-eb95-476d-af6a-917f269a0814.cssx\39e5cb39-cd18-4e1a-9c25-72bd1ad41b49.csman
```

I can open this file fine via the open window in notepad++, or via the explorer. However, opening via the Run window doesn't work. It gives an 'cannot find the file' dialog. When I query the filesystem in C# with:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Jan\...")
var fil = dir.GetFiles("*.csman")[0];
```

The file is also in the list of returned files but I can't do a:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(fil.FullName);
```

Because this fails with an 'incorrect data at (1,1)' error. Because the `XmlDocument` thinks the file is empty. However a `File.ReadAllBytes` on this file succeeds. This works:

```
var buf = File.ReadAllBytes(fil.FullName);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(buf, 0, (int) buf.Length);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    xmlDoc.Load(ms);
}
```

The problem doesn't occur when calling...

```
xmlDoc.Save(fil.FullName);
```

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: 204 characters is well short of any limits. Think again.

Comment: Many APIs in windows have a 260 char limit, but your 204 chars are below that, so that's not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) expects a string that directly contains the XML data.

> Parameters
>   xml
>       Type: System.String
>       String containing the XML document to load.

It is therefore interpreting the path-string as if it were XML (which will obviously be invalid, which is why the exception is thrown).

Use the  [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method instead.

> Parameters
>   filename
>       Type: System.String
>       URL for the file containing the XML document to load. The URL can be either a local file or an HTTP URL (a Web address).

You don't face the problem when calling  [`XmlDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx), because, like `Load`, it's single parameter represents the path to the file.

Basically, the somewhat long file-path you've got there is a red-herring and not the root-cause of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @CodeBlend: The method is already a hyperlink to the same MSDN page in my answer :)

Comment: my bad, I need look more closely, in fact its linked twice so double bad points for me

Answer (score 2):

And your other problem:
Windows "Run" requires quotes around the path name if there are spaces in it.